# Django Rest Framework how to post data on the browsable API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im kind of new to Django Rest Framework. I know it is possible to post data using the Browsable API, I just don't know how. I have this simple view:

```
class ProcessBill(APIView):

    def post(self, request):

        bill_data = request.data
        print(bill_data)

        return Response("just a test", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I go to the url that points to this view, I get the rest_framework browsable api view with the response from the server `method not allowed` which is understandable cause I am not setting a `def get()` method. But ... how can I POST the data? I was expecting a form of some kind somewhere.

**EDIT**
This is a screenshot of how the browsable API looks for me, it is in spanish. The `view` is the same I wrote above but in spanish. As you can see ... no form for POST data :/ .

[image]

Comment: You must be seeing a text box below labeled as - `Content`. Can you share screenshot of how your browser window looks like?

Comment: @RohitJain Thans for the answer. Just added it as an edit.

Comment: You need to define a `get_serializer_class()` method or `serializer_class` attribute in your view.

Comment: @RohitJain Did that but it doesn't work. Also, it doesn't make much sense that it would solve it. Could you point me to the docs, I've tried to find info about "setting up" the Browsable Api but coulnd't find any. Looks like it is supposed to work out of the box.

Comment: @alejoss I think that your post method needs to accept the `format` kwarg, but posting should generally work as far as I know. Have you tried to POST some data from command line (i.e. using `curl`?) to see if the server accepts it?

Comment: I tried your code, and I was seeing the same thing you were: just an `OPTIONS` button.  But, suddenly I was also presented with a textbox and a `POST` button. However, I cannot get back to the original state where only an `OPTIONS` button was displayed, so I don't know what I did.  I commented out `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` in settings.py, which the tutorial said to add, and I shut down the server a couple of times.  I also played around with the `OPTIONS` button.  Sorry, I can't be more helpful.

Comment: did you get the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are new I will recommend you to use [Generic views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/), it will save you lot of time and make your life easier:

```py
class ProcessBillListCreateApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = ProcessBill
    queryset = ProcessBill.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProcessBillSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        bill_data = request.data
        print(bill_data)
        return bill_data
```

I will recommend to go also through [DRF Tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) to the different way to implement your endpoint and some advanced feature like *Generic views*, *Permessions*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the user has read-only permission. If this is the case make sure the user is properly authenticated or remove the configuration from the projects settings.py if it is not necessary as shown below.

````
    ```#'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
       # 'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
       #],```
````

Read more on permissions [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/).