# Django REST Framework not generating form in Browsable API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Ok, I have a `GenericAPIView` that is supposed to generate a form in the Browsable API cause it declares a `post` method:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from transacciones.serializers import BillSerializer


class ProcessBill(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = BillSerializer

    def post(self, request):

        recieved_data = request.data

        print(recieved_data)

        return Response("Processed Bill", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

But it doesn't generate a form. The view looks like this (it is in spanish, I translated the code to english so it is be more confortable to read):

[image]

I understand I get a `405 Method not Allowed` cause I don't define a `get` method, only a `post`.

Im using Django 1.8, Django REST Framework 3.3.1 and python 3.4. I'm lost here. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Also, if I use Postman (Chrome add on) the view responds correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Rest Framework how to post data on the browsable API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342280/django-rest-framework-how-to-post-data-on-the-browsable-api)

Comment: @Geotob This question uses a `GenericAPIView`, the old one uses a `APIView`. The difference is stated in the answer to this question by TomChristie : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616489/django-rest-framework-autogenerate-form-in-browsable-api

Comment: Anyway I thought It might be a good idea to create a new question, maybe it wasn't a good idea. I could delete one of them.

Comment: Sorry I didn't spot this! :( `GenericAPIViews` use a `create(request, *args, **kwargs)` method, not `post`

Comment: @Geotob tried the create method, doesn't work. Anyway, `GenericAPIView` extends from the `APIView`, that what the docs say ... so it should have a `post` method.

Comment: Testing with a similar setup, this seems to work just fine. Can you post your `BillSerializer`?

Comment: Does anyone know if the browsable API has to be activated somehow?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` then you will have to define permission_classes which can be custom.

```
class ObjectDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Object RUD (Read Update Delete) API
    """
    permission_classes = ( checkUserPermission, )
    queryset = Object.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
```

OR If you want to just test this, use `permission_classes = ( AllowAny, )`

```
class ObjectDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Object RUD (Read Update Delete) API
    """
    permission_classes = ( AllowAny, )
    queryset = Object.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from rest_framework.mixins import CreateModelMixin
from rest_framework.response import Response

from transacciones.serializers import BillSerializer


class ProcessBill(CreateModelMixin, GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = BillSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do whatever you want here

        # Then invoke the create method and create your instance
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Or as an alternative, you just inherit from `CreateAPIView` which does essentially the same as the code above :)

Comment: hm yea @alejoss i didn't notice that generics need the `post` method.. too used to viewsets. learned something new:) see the edit above, works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, with postman I saw it was a credential issue, so changing current user status to staff solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. In my case, the mistake was in the serializer, where I used `django.db.models.CharField(...)` instead of `rest_framework.serializers.CharField(...)`.